# Multi-threading improvement when reading in CSV using Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

Wondering if the below makes sense.  The Data.csv file is about 8 GB.  My laptop has 64GB of RAM with 12 threads.  Is this the kind of improvement I should see from multi-threading?  Or is there something else I should do here?

```
@time CSV.read(raw"Data.csv", DataFrame, ntasks=1); # one thread
```

139.160430 seconds

```
@time CSV.read(raw"Data.csv", DataFrame, ntasks=8); # 8 threads
```

113.964781 seconds

```
@time CSV.read(raw"Data.csv", DataFrame, ntasks=12); # 12 threads
```

112.279668 seconds

As indicated in the above, I tried these different ntasks= options to select different thread counts, but I am new to multi-threading, so trying to get a sense of the level of improvement I should expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading data from disk, the bottleneck will typically be the disk, so adding threads will not improve that. The speedup you see might be a little parsing improvement.

Comment: ok - so, what is the point of multi-threading if the disc is the bottleneck?  I guess I am just too new to understand the point....I recognize I can do more on my side (and I will) but figured I'd ask the follow up.

Comment: The point is that you can get a faster disk (SSD). You could try to use a tool such as ImDisk to create a RAM disk, and see if that speeds things up. https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/

Comment: On my 4-core machine with an SSD, reading the 87MB CSV [here](https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/blob/main/files/customers/customers-500000.zip), `ntasks=1` gives an average time of 484ms versus 123ms for `ntasks=4`.